# Ionic-Multiple views in a page overlap

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a page where I load contents from two different html pages.
The problem is that the 2 views overlap each other.
This is my code for the main page where both the views will be loaded.

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" ui-view="set">
            </div> 
            <div class="col" ui-view="set">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It doesn't matter what I load into these views, a single line or a slide-box they always overlap.Ionic's CSS should take care of the the divs with "col" class and keep them separate.But it doesn't seem to be happening.Am I doing something wrong or do I need to add some CSS styling to get this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the views I was loading. Each of the html page I was loading had content inside the `<ion-content`> tags i.e.

...
..

The views stopped overlapping after I removed the `<ion-content>` tags.
I'm not sure why this is so. If someone can help understand this it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me but I don´t understand the reason... any way thank you